# Convert to date type in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column in Snowflake table which contains date with both formats:

- Wed Sep 30 00:00:00 UTC 2020
- 2023-06-08

How to convert this column to date type?

Thanks in advance!

Function to_timestamp is not correct for ,,Wed Sep 30 00:00:00 UTC 2020".

Comment: Do you want a Date datatype or a Timestamp datatype? You'd need to create a new column with the required datatype, insert the data from the existing column to the new column (transforming it on the way) and then you could drop the old column and rename the new column. You'd probably need to move the data in two stages, one for each format pattern. Use TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP (or TRY_TO_DATE) and then you wont get errors and you can filter out the records where this function returns nulls

Comment: @NickW but then I will lose rows

Comment: I’m confused - what in anything I suggested would lead to you losing rows? What do you mean by losing rows - rows being deleted or rows without the correct value in this column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. for to_date function you need to specify the timestamp format.
2. Since you have the timestamp in to different formats, you can use case clause and regexp

Try this:

```
-- Create the table
CREATE TABLE your_table_name (
    timestamp_column STRING
);

-- Insert the sample data
INSERT INTO your_table_name (timestamp_column)
VALUES
    ('Wed Sep 30 00:00:00 UTC 2020'),
    ('2023-06-08');
```

Then use the query:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN timestamp_column REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z]{3} [a-zA-Z]{3} [0-9]{1,2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} UTC [0-9]{4}$' THEN 
            TO_DATE(timestamp_column, 'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS UTC YYYY')
        WHEN timestamp_column REGEXP '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$' THEN 
            TO_DATE(timestamp_column, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
        ELSE NULL
    END AS formatted_date
FROM your_table_name;
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks! :D